# How can I filter content of a web page?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, web-filtering

I wanted to know, if is there any setting/addon available in Mozilla Firefox or in Google Chrome by which I can filter the content of my choice on any web page.

To be more clear, **I want to save my data usage**, if I am visiting any blog or any other site out there, sometime I see there is lots of content, like ads, social plugins etc which I do not require apart from the content I was looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is and addon for firefox which named addsblock you can download it from following link:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/?src=hp-dl-mostpopular

from this link:

> Annoyed by adverts? Troubled by tracking? Bothered by banners? Install Adblock Plus now to regain control of the internet and change the way that you view the web.

and there is another one which named NoScript you can download it from following link:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/?src=hp-dl-mostpopular

from this link:

> The best security you can get in a web browser!
>   Allow active content to run only from sites you trust, and protect yourself against XSS and Clickjacking attacks.

**You can block some disturb portions of any sites by these plugins but they are not accurate.**

Comment: I found NoScript awesome... but could not configure Adblock-plus. after installing this, it still allows ads to display over web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Adblock Plus is available for Chrome (from the Chrome Webstore) as well as Firefox.
You can either allow Adblock Plus to remove advertising as it thinks fit or you can specifically block content using specific keywords.